# Table of conclusions

Tags: table-of-contents

I wish my long thesis could have an automatic ''table of conclusions'' where all key findings are listed with links to where they appear.

Does anything like this exist in `LaTeX`? Imagine:

```
 \finding[The answer was 42.]{42 was the answer to the great question.}
```

---

### Table of Conclusions

Chap 1:

The answer was 42. . . . . . p. 10

Comment: Do these `\finding`s have a number associated with them? If not, what should happen when you have no findings in Chapter 2, but findings in both Chapter 1 and 3? Should one just not print `Chap 2:`?

Comment: A great package would allow skipping chapters, numbering, and ordering by appearance or some importance metric.

Comment: A great user would supply the community with [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can use as a playground so we don't have to create something from scratch.

Comment: @JonathanAbbott: You're invited by heart to provide such a package and upload to CTAN such that anybody can gain benefit of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request is quite straight forward for easy setups, using `tocloft` and its `\newlistof` command.

The `\findings` command is similar to `\chapter` etc. The starred version does just print the finding text (3rd. argument), without number,the optional argument is used for the `List of Conclusions` and the 3rd one is the always displayed one.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listfindingsname}{List of conclusions}

\newlistof[chapter]{findings}{fin}{\listfindingsname}


\NewDocumentCommand{\findings}{so+m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    {\bfseries #3}%
  }{%
    \refstepcounter{findings}%
    {\bfseries\thefindings\ #3}%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \addcontentsline{fin}{findings}{\protect\numberline{\thefindings~}#2}%
    }{%
      \addcontentsline{fin}{findings}{\protect\numberline{\thefindings~}#3}%
    }%
  }%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffindings

\chapter{What should a new user do on TeX.SX}

\findings{He shall provide a MWE}

\chapter{Why should he provide a MWE}

\findings[To ease the work of users here]{To ease the work of users here in order to find some solution and not have to do wild guesses about the request}

\chapter{What do we do with users not providing a MWE}

\findings*{We post a simple solution and keep the better one for us ;-)}


\end{document}
```

[image]